# What api to use GSuite and google identity on a company intranet

Tags: javascript, google-identity, google-workspace

Im making an intranet software for my company and we have a g-suite account with all the employees accounts. i was looking in the google identity documentation and g-suite documentation and didnt find a way to integrate this into a javascript frontend app. What API exacyly should i use to validate user credentials on gsuite?

Answer (score 2):

oAuth2 would be the method for user verification:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

You would have the user authenticate their google account via oAuth2 and redirect back to your site where you would do a logical check, say, take the email address from the payload and strip out the domain and ensure the domain was your company's domain. If it is... let them proceed.

Comment: This is quite long asked question, but I wish you @joshinik will be able to see and answer me, is my company need to pay more to enable the feature or access to GCP? I did POC to my team leader, and when go to G Suite GCP console, the screen said that we need to pay more. So I just curious why is it difference from my private GCP account?